# Instantiate Object Java

Tags: java, object, loops, properties

Let's say I have 10 objects. Now, I create them and the only way I store them is a String array of some value in that object. I don't store the actual objects themselves anywhere. Is there any way I can access the object based on that array of strings?

```
String[] someArray = new String[10];


 some loop (i = 1 to 10)

       Object newObject = new Object("hello" + i);

       someArray[i] = newObject.returnSomeStringInTheObject();

repeat
```

Now at this point I have an array of Strings. Can I access the Object created at i=3 for example?

Each string is different.

Comment: reformatted the code to appear better

Comment: Why do you want to store in String Array? Why not ObjectType Array?

Comment: Constraints of the program. It has to be an array of strings. Otherwise, I definitely would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about saving a HashMap that maps a string from the array to the actual object?
If you don't keep a reference to the object somewhere in the code, it may be deleted from memory by the garbage collector and you have no control on this process. Even it it's not deleted yet when you want to access it, you will have no actual reference to it which you can use.

Comment: That's a good solution but that *in fact* prescribes storing actual objects, which contradicts to OP's intentions.

Comment: If I understand correctly 'user' needs it to be represented in a string array. I don't think it necessarily means (s)he can't keep another representation in memory. If the requirements forbid it, then I guess another solution is needed (serialization probably, as was suggested here)

Comment: That answered it:  If you don't keep a reference to the object somewhere in the code, it may be deleted from memory by the garbage collector and you have no control on this process.

Comment: That's why I wrote that your solution is good. But you could have proposed OP to give up array for a list :)

Comment: I thought it may be possible in some way to access the object with the array of strings, since the string is stored by a call to the object's toString() method, therefore referencing the object in some way. But, of course, the toString() just returns a string and store that in the array, with no reference to the object itself.

Answer (score 4):

Because each of your string is different, I would use a map, something like:

```
final Map<String, Object> someMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// some loop (i = 1 to 10)

   Object newObject = new Object("hello" + i);
   someMap.put(newObject.returnSomeStringInTheObject(), newObject);

// repeat
```

You can then use the map to get back an object from its "someString"

Comment: Is there any particular reason to declare `HashMap` as `Map`? I've seen some telling not to declare `HashMap map = new HashMap()`.

Comment: It's usually better to use interfaces (`Map` is, `HashMap` is an implementation) for types declaration

Comment: Can you explain me why this is advantageous? I was used to not using interfaces.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383726/java-declaring-from-interface-type-instead-of-class

Answer (score 2):

When you go for the next iteration in your loop your object isn't accessible anymore, so you can't access it in any way. Still, you can create some kind of converter from your object class to a string, and vice versa. This way, you'll be able to *reconstruct* the object:

```
public getObjectFromString(String string) {
    return YourClass.createFromString(string);
}

public getStringFromObject(YourClass obj) {
    Return obj.toString();
}
```

Comment: Ok, so that object is done and gone once the next loop iteration starts?

Comment: That particular instance yes, it'll be garbage collected. But with the 'converter approach' you'll be able to create, or reconstruct, an object with so-called object identity, from a stored string. That way, you have to ensure a one-to-one correspondence between a string and an object.

Comment: The first sentence answered it all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to convert a string representation of an instance into the  Object.

Override the toString method inside your class: This will create String representation of your object.

```
public String toString(){
   return "attr1 :"+ value1
          + "; attr2 :"+ value2;  
}
```

To get the value back; you need to parse the String representation of your object and create new object.

```
String x = someArray[i]; //read toString value from array
```

In above case key each attribute is separated by a semi colon. And attribute name and value are separated by colon(:). So you can parse using your String utilities.

Comment: This will not get him the same object though (not sure if that's what he's asking).

Comment: Yes that is what I'm asking. I'm looking to access the individual objects after the fact. They've each been created in the loop. In fact, that loop created 10 objects. But now, I don't have any instances of them. All I have is an array of Strings. And as far as I know, each String is a pointer to the object, since the value came from the object.

Comment: Not entirely sure. You would have to create a new Object and instantiate it with these values, so it won't be a reference to the ones you created initially.

Comment: I belive @user wants to write state of object as String into and String array. So you need to do something as i have suggested. But if you want to store the state in a file then Serialization can help you.

Comment: @user: no. A String is basically an array of characters. It doesn't have any pointer to the object that was used to create the string. If you want to have access the the objects created in the loop, you need to store thos instances inside a clooection (an array of objects, or a List, or whatever).

Comment: @user No, the string has no clue about its surrounding object. If you don't store a reference to the object, garbage collecting will delete it. However, since you have a reference to your string (in the array), that string will remain

Comment: @Heuster  Excellent. So that array is just storing strings and is no way linked to the objects?

Comment: I believe that's the answer I was looking for guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is not possible. Once you exit the loop that created the Objects, the objects are gone unless you store them somewhere, which you say you can't do.

You can, however, construct a new object that is identical to the previous one

```
 class myObject {
     public myObject(String str){
          someStringInThisObject = str
     }
}
```

then, in your main class:

```
 myObject m = new myObject(someArray[i]);
```