# Declaring from Interface type, instead of class type, doesn't seem Polymorphic or more general

Tags: java, generics, types, polymorphism

I'm learning that it is generally better to make the declared type as general as possible, but I'm not sure why. For example, in most cases, this...

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

is considered better than this:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

One of the reasons given for this preference is quoted below( [Java - declaring from Interface type instead of Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383726/java-declaring-from-interface-type-instead-of-class))

> Yes, you are correct. You should declare as the most general type providing the methods you >use.This is the concept of polymorphism.

However, polymorphism usually increases the amount of methods available to you because you can also access the methods of your super-types. But, in the case of declaring with interface types you actually restrict the number of methods available to you because you can only access methods in the interface, and you cannot access those just belonging to the class type.

So is this really Polymorphism? and why is it considered "more general" when it seems more restrictive, if anything, to me? What am I missing?

Comment: Who says polymorphism increases the number of your available methods? The `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();` thing is indeed better practice.

Comment: As @webuster says, the goal of polymorphism is to provide a single interface over multiple types, not to increase the number of functions you have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

is generally preferred over

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

because usually you do not need methods that are specific to `ArrayList`.  Usually, the methods defined in `List` are more than enough to satisfy typical needs.  This allows you to change the implementation without changing the rest of the code, like this:

```
List<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>();
```

and nothing else changes.

Only use the specific type for the variable if you need the methods that are specific to that type.  Only use `ArrayList` for your variable if you really do need `ArrayList`-specific methods.

Comment: You said "This allows you to change the implementation without changing the rest of the code." But nothing is stopping me from writing:       LinkedList<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>(); right?

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from writing that; it's OK.  It's required if you use `LinkedList`-specific methods.

Comment: But if I can change the implementation without changing the code using both ways, why restrict myself to the interface?

Comment: The benefit is that the code that uses the variable doesn't need to know or care which implementation is being used.  You don't have to restrict yourself to the interface if you don't find that benefit useful.

Comment: @Kevin the advantage can't be seen if you only have 1 variable. But if you instead have for example a class that accepts List as a function parameter, and you invoke that function in 100 different locations, you can change internal structure in one place without breaking the code.

Comment: @korhner Can I be a pain and ask you to explain this bit in more detail: "you can change internal structure in one place without breaking the code" - what internal structure in what place?

Comment: Say, for example, you have a class that has a linked list of items. You have a get method that returns that list. Now hundreds of objects use that class and call get list so they can iterate and do something to items. However, one day, you decide to change collection type to ArrayList for a reason. If you made the method return List instead of LinkedList, you would end up with more flexible code and would have to do almost no changes to the code. Hope I explained it better now :)

Comment: @korhner Great, I now see the value of being general from the callers perspective. But, I think my short follow up comment to ike_love below might explain most clearly what sill remains to be answered. - at least in my tangled mind that is :-p

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a method like this:

```
public void doSomething(ArrayList<String> items) {
  // do something with the list
}
```

How do you call this method?

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
doSomething(list1); // good
LinkedList<String> list2 = new LinkedList<String>();
doSomething(list2); // bad
// you'd have to make a new array list and add all the items from your linked list to it
doSomething(new ArrayList<String>(list2));
```

Both list1 and list2 are List's but because you made your method signature requires ArrayList you cannot pass in LinkedList, or better yet List.  That is why you code to an interface - it allows you to write one method that supports any implementation of List.

If you want to make it even better, use Collection instead of list, it will support Set's as well then.

As far as "increases the amount of methods available" - what method would you call on ArrayList that is not available on List? One of the benefits of interfaces is that they hide implementation complexities from you and allows you to use difference classes via a well defined interface that hides the details of the underlying implementation.

Comment: I see from your example, that if the "doSomething" method's parameter was of type List, then it could be utilized by both ArrayStacks and LinkedStacks - a clear bonus. But this bonus is available whether or not,for example, list1 is declared as List-type or ArrayList-type. So what's the advantage there, specifically??

Comment: @KevinMcInerney  that's the "trick" - the benefit isn't when you declare your list1 as List vs. ArrayList inside of your own method, it's when you declare method signatures like doSomething(List) vs doSomething(ArrayList). 

As a side note, some IDEs have a feature where you can type up a function name + return type and if the function doesn't exist, the IDE will give you the option to auto-create it. Using List<T> vs. ArrayList<T> will produce cleaner method signature off the bat.

Comment: Can I argue then, that its better -all things being equal- to declare my list as ArrayList inside my own method - so that I can also access my class methods too. Why not? As we've seen, it won't prevent me from availing of a suitably general method signature, elsewhere. #SryForMilkingThisToDeath

Comment: @KevinMcInerney - unless you rely on methods specific to ArrayList - ensureCapacity(int), trimToSize() or removeRange(int, int) - using List is better. Or better yet Collection, it is even more flexible because it accepts Sets too. It makes your code easier to read and refactor.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia defines Polymorphism as follows:

> In programming languages and type theory, polymorphism (from Greek πολύς, polys, "many, much" and μορφή, morphē, "form, shape") is the provision of a single interface to entities of different types.

Polymorphism enables writing algorithms that can work on more than one type, therefore increasing code reuse.

For instance, if we have a method

```
void sort(ArrayList<String> list);
```

that method can only be used for sorting an `ArrayList<String>`. That's not very useful. But if you have

```
<T> void sort(ArrayList<T> list);
```

the method can be applied to far more types, and is therefore more useful. But it can still only sort ArrayLists. Taking the idea farther, we have

```
<T> void sort(List<T> list);
```

which can sort any kind of list, whatever its provenance or internal representation.

Generally, your methods should require as little as possible of their arguments, to be useful in as many circumstances as possible.

Comment: Hope this isn't off topic, but is the first <T> in this code doing something? <T> void sort(ArrayList<T> list);

Comment: Yes, it declares a type parameter, which demonstrates parametric polymorphism (the second step, from ArrayList to List, demonstrates subtype polymorphism).