# Difference between interface and class objects

Tags: java, class, oop, interface

I'm reading through the Oracle doc, but I don't get something.

Suppose I have

```
public interface a {
    //some methods
}
public class b implements a {
    //some methods
}
```

What would be the difference between this:

```
a asd=new b();
```

and this:

```
b asf=new b();
```

Comment: Second one does not compile

Comment: You need to clarify your understanding of `interface`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383726/java-declaring-from-interface-type-instead-of-class

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing. At least not compile.

```
a asd=new a(); // you can't instantiate an interface
```

and

```
b asf=new a(); // you can't instantiate an interface
```

You can do followings.

```
b asd=new b();
```

and

```
a asd=new b();
```

Comment: I meant `b`, excuse me.

Answer (score 1):

let say we have class  b and interface a:

```
public interface a{
  void foo();
}
public class b implements a{
  @Override
  void foo(){}
  void bar(){}
}
```

then we create two instances:

```
a asd=new b();
b asf=new b();
```

now `asd`is instance of 'a' so it can access only methods declared in interface `a` (in this case method `foo`)

`asf` from other hand is instance of `b` so it can access both method defined in class `b`

Answer (score 0):

1. you cannot instantiate an interface
2. if we suppose you mean a parent class, in the first case you cannot the access method(s) of class b

Suppose you have these classes:

```
public class a {
//some methods
}
public class b extends a {
//some methods
    type method1(args) {...}
}
```

What would be the difference between?

```
a asd=new b(); // you cannot call method1 using asd
```

and

```
b asf=new b();
```

Answer (score 0):

a asd = new b() -- can be resolved at runtime

b bsd = new b() -- can be resolved at compile time.