# trying to pass arraylist to one form to another form

Tags: java, inheritance

Trying to get the person ArrayList passed from oca project to the main form then pass the list to the assign bonus form. It passes to the main form correctly but can't seem to get seem to retrieve the ArrayList in assign bonus. Every time it runs I get an error saying out of bounds error from the system.out part when trying to get 1 of the person list.

```
package oca.project;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class OCAProject {

 static ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         CEO JamesMint = new CEO();
        //making objects 
 AdministrationManager BillJohns = new AdministrationManager(JamesMint);
FinancialAdministrator EricWhite = new FinancialAdministrator(JamesMint);
 persons.add(JamesMint);
 persons.add(BillJohns);
persons.add(EricWhite);

 //declaring form and passing arraylist as parameter
        MainForm frame = new MainForm(persons);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

main form class

```
package oca.project;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  //array list to hold the report items
    private ArrayList<PayrollReportItem> payRolllist = new ArrayList<>();

  AssignBonusForm assignFrame = new AssignBonusForm(payRolllist);
void setList(ArrayList<Person> persons) {
//sets arraylist

      assignFrame.setPersons(persons);


   }
 public MainForm(ArrayList<Person> persons) {
           initComponents();
        setList(persons);
       }

 private void btnAssignBonusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

//to open assign bonus form
      assignFrame.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();


    }
```

assign bonus form

```
package oca.project;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class AssignBonusForm extends javax.swing.JFrame  {

  ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
public AssignBonusForm(ArrayList<PayrollReportItem> payRolllist) {
        initComponents();

      System.out.println(persons.get(1));
    } 
private AssignBonusForm() {


    }
public void setPersons(ArrayList<Person> persons) {
    this.persons = persons;
    }

    public ArrayList<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't called `setPersons` yet, so the ArrayList doesn't have the values from the other class.

Comment: Also consider making the declared type always of some interface, e.g. `List` instead of some implementation detail like `ArrayList`, so: `ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();` should become `List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();` See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383726/java-declaring-from-interface-type-instead-of-class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that this is the issue (since I don't know Java THAT in depth), but perhaps in `MainForm`, you are calling the constructor to `AssignBonusForm` before you set the list? I'm not entirely sure if member data is initialized first or if the constructor is called first, but if member data is initialized first, then the issue is that you haven't set the value of `payRolllist` when you called the `AssignBonusForm` constructor. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but it didn't work. Still having the same problem.