# Convert 2D jagged array to proper array Java

Tags: java, loops, indexing, jagged-arrays

I am trying to solve the following problem: I have a 2D jagged array

```
[[1, 2], [1], [3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

which I would like to convert to a normal 2D array. Currently, I managed to get this one

```
[[1, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [3, 4, 0, 0], [2, 3, 4, 0]]
```

but that is not what I want. Goal is to have a normal array indices equaling the original jagged one.
***In other words, I would like to match the value from the original jagged array to the index starting from 1 in the new proper array.*** Here is my desired output

```
[[1, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 4], [0, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Here is my code which produces this array, which is not quite what I would like to have:

```
[[1, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [3, 4, 0, 0], [2, 3, 4, 0]]
```

```
import java.util.*;

public class MultiDarrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Get number of two parameters: cyclists and bicycles: ");

        int c = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("cyclists: " + c + " " + "bicycles: " + b);

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> multilist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {

            List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int num = sc.nextInt();
            for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {

                int elem = sc.nextInt();
                integers.add(elem);
            }
            multilist.add((ArrayList<Integer>) integers);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < multilist.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Elements are: " + multilist.get(i));
        }
        sc.close();

        int[][] array = new int[multilist.size()][b];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = new int[multilist.get(i).size()];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < multilist.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < multilist.get(i).size(); j++) {
                array[i][j] = multilist.get(i).get(j);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));

        int[][] full_array = new int[c][b];
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(full_array));

        // copy elements from jagged to normal 2D array
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                full_array[i][j] = array[i][j];
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(full_array));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Get number of two parameters: cyclists and bicycles: 
4 4
cyclists: 4 bicycles: 4
2 1 2
1 1
2 3 4
3 2 3 4
Elements are: [1, 2]
Elements are: [1]
Elements are: [3, 4]
Elements are: [2, 3, 4]
[[1, 2], [1], [3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [3, 4, 0, 0], [2, 3, 4, 0]]
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry for making it not clear. What I mean is that if I have an array ```[3,4]``` , I would like to get in the output ```[0,0,3,4]``` so I would like to match the value from the original jagged array to the index starting from 1 in the new proper array. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to write the values to the correct indices they represent, then you can't just do `full_array[i][j] = array[i][j]`, because this ignores the value and just simply "fills" the array, because `j` just increments normally.
What you actually need to do is use the value of `array[i][j]` as index specification:

```
full_array[i][array[i][j] - 1] = array[i][j];
```

Mind that you need to reduce 1, because your values start from "1", but array indices from "0".

Now the output is like you expect it to be:

> [[1, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 4], [0, 2, 3, 4]]

---

Now to some minor code improvements.

1. `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> multilist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();` should be refactored to `List<List<Integer>> multilist = new ArrayList<>();`, because should declare your types as *open* as they could be, but as *narrow* as they need to be. You need a List, but you actually don't care it they are an ArrayList or for example a LinkedList. Also read [Java - declaring from Interface type instead of Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383726/java-declaring-from-interface-type-instead-of-class).
2. This cast `multilist.add((ArrayList<Integer>) integers)` is not needed. You had to added because you (correctly) declared `integers` as `List<Integer>` instead of `ArrayList<Integer>`, but since we fixed that in "1." you don't need it anymore.
3. ```
   for (int i = 0; i < multilist.size(); i++) {
       System.out.println("Elements are: " + multilist.get(i));
   }
   ```

   can be replace with an enhanced-for-loop:

   ```
   for (List<Integer> integers : multilist) {
       System.out.println("Elements are: " + integers);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are several general issues with the code in the current form.

It's annoying to test it, because you always have to enter the input values. Define them once, so that you can quickly and easily test your code.

The use of `List` is not really necessary. When your input and output really are `int[]` arrays, you can implement your conversions based on those. Although in many cases, `List` has advantages, in doubt you could add conversion methods between `int[]` and `List<Integer>` and between `int[][]` and `List<List<Integer>>`.

In general, when you have a task with a multidimensional data structure like an `int[][]` or a `List<List<Integer>>`, and you want to perform an operation on the inner elements, it is beneficial to create a dedicated method for that. As a simplified example: When you have a method like

```
static void addToEachElement2D(int array[][], int valueToAdd) { ... }
```

then this method could/should be implemented based on a method

```
static void addToEachElement1D(int array[], int valueToAdd) { ... }
```

which simplifies the implementation of the `2D` variant, and may also serve as a useful building block for other tasks.

---

However, here is one possible solution for the given task:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class MultiDarrays
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int array[][] = new int[][]
        {
            { 1, 2 },
            { 1 },
            { 3, 4 },
            { 2, 3, 4 } 
        };

        int result[][] = unjag(array);    
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
    }

    private static int[][] unjag(int array[][])
    {
        int width = computeMaxValue(array);
        return unjag(array, width);
    }

    private static int[][] unjag(int array[][], int width)
    {
        int result[][] = new int[array.length][width];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = unjag(array[i], width);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int[] unjag(int array[], int width)
    {
        int result[] = new int[width];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            int value = array[i];
            result[value - 1] = value;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int computeMaxValue(int array[][])
    {
        return Stream.of(array)
            .flatMapToInt(a -> IntStream.of(a))
            .max().getAsInt();
    }
}
```

It computes the maximum value of any of the inner arrays, which is also the width of the resulting 2D array. Then it "unjags" the 2D array by "unjagging" each row of the input array to have the desired width.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't avoid two loops, but that is all:

1. Calculate the width for the proper array via checking the first element of each sub-array
2. Make the copies into the proper array.

Lists are not involved.
Code with your example numbers:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int data[][]={{1, 2}, {1}, {3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}};
  int maxwidth=0;
  for(int line[]: data){
    maxwidth=Math.max(maxwidth, line[0]-1+line.length);
  }
  System.out.println(maxwidth);
  int proper[][]=new int[data.length][maxwidth];
  for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    int line[]=data[i];
    System.arraycopy(line, 0, proper[i], line[0]-1, line.length);
  }

  for(int line[]: proper){
    for(int i=0;i<line.length-1;i++)
      System.out.print(line[i]+",");
    System.out.println(line[line.length-1]);
  }
}
```

---

If @Tom is right about putting individual elements into individual locations (not just to a continuous "slot" indexed by the first element):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int data[][]={{1, 2}, {1}, {3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 5}};
  int max=0;
  for(int line[]: data)
    for(int val: line)
      max=Math.max(max,val);
  System.out.println(max);
  int proper[][]=new int[data.length][max];
  for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    int line[]=data[i];
    for(int val: line)
      proper[i][val-1]=val;
  }

  for(int line[]: proper){
    for(int i=0;i<line.length-1;i++)
      System.out.print(line[i]+",");
    System.out.println(line[line.length-1]);
  }
}
```

I really can not tell which approach you meant, and the example numbers are very unhelpful here.

Comment: I'd might be missing something, but your calculation of max length looks incorrect. Just checking the first item of each sub-array plus the sub-array length won't help you, when you have short sub-arrays with large values. For example add `{1,5}` to your example array to see what I mean.

Comment: @Tom, I understand what you mean, but I am not sure if that is what OP meant or not.