# why cant we access the method2-interface

Tags: java, interface

Why cant we access the `method2`? I mean d is instance of A or am i wrong?

```
public class MainPage {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                
            interfaceExample d=new A();
            d.method1();
            //d.method2(); this is not accessible why?
    
                
        }
            
    }
    
    interface interfaceExample{
        void method1();
    }
    class A implements interfaceExample{
    
        @Override
        public void method1() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
        public void method2() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383726/java-declaring-from-interface-type-instead-of-class

Comment: When you wrote `interfaceExample d=new A();`, you told Java to forget that `d` was anything but an `interfaceExample`.  Java listened.  Java forgot that `d` was anything but an `interfaceExample`.